# Memory mirroring for a ring buffer on Linux

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, circular-buffer

I use an anonymous mmap to allocate a giant chunk of memory. There are several contiguous pages in this that I'd like to turn into a ring buffer, using virtual memory mirroring.

[This example on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Circular_buffer&oldid=588930355#Optimized_POSIX_implementation) shows what I'm meaning by virtual memory mirroring.

Say the first 14 blocks below are the pages in my giant chunk. I'd like to virtually map pages 6 and 7 to another two consecutive locations.

```
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13].......[6][7][6][7]
```

Mike Ash gives [a rundown](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-02-03-ring-buffers-and-mirrored-memory-part-i.html) of what I want to do, but using mach specific APIs.

How can this be done on Linux?

Comment: What's wrong with that example on Wikipedia?

Comment: @pentadecagon I already have a big chunk of memory, a couple of pages from within I want to mirror. The Wikipedia example requires allocating new memory.

Comment: Not really, all it requires is a file descriptor that it can `mmap` twice, it doesn't care where it came from. The idea being that you want the complete buffer to be mirrored (which is obviously what _most_ people want). If you only want to mirror a part of the memory block, simply use something other than zero for `offset`. The only other possible way of mirroring pages is using `remap_file_pages`, and this, too, requires a memory mapping (so you gain nothing, really). You lose something though... portability.

Comment: @Damon thanks, `remap_file_pages` is what I was looking for

Comment: @max @damon Alas, `remap_file_pages` is marked deprecated in recent Linux versions.  Probably better to use `mmap`.

Comment: @Max here is what you were looking for https://github.com/vitalyvch/rng_buf

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to achieve with anonymous mappings. You can, however, use [memfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html) or create a temporary file on tmpfs (so that it won't ever be stored to disk, except by "swapping") and do shared mappings on that file descriptor, adjacent to each other.

[remap_file_pages(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/remap_file_pages.2.html) is just a performance hack and not any more powerful than classic mmap/mremap calls, and it can't operate on anonymous mappings either.

Related: [Linux mremap without freeing the old mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904547/linux-mremap-without-freeing-the-old-mapping)